# Search for a specific digit in an integer

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a really quick method in MATLAB of searching for a specific digit within an integer, ideally in a given position. For example:

Simple case...

I want to look through an array of integers and return all those which contain the number 1 eg 1234, 4321, 6515, 847251737 etc

More complex case...

I want to loop through an array of integers and return all those which contain the number 1 in the third digit eg 6218473, 541846, 3115473 BUT 175846 would not be returned.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

There's a few answers here already, I'll throw my try into the pot.

Conversion to string can be expensive, so if it can be avoided, it should be.

```
n = 1:100000; % sample numbers
m = 3; % digit to check
x = 1; % number to find

% Length of the numbers in digits
num_length = floor(log10(abs(n)))+1;

% digit (from the left) to check
num_place = num_length-m;

% get the digit
digit_in_place = mod(floor(abs(n)./(10.^num_place)),10);

found_number = n(digit_in_place==x);
```

Answer (score 3):

By casting to strings, the trick to vectorising is just to make sure `x` is a column vector. `x(:)` guarantees this. Also you need to left-align the strings which is done with the format specifier `'%-d'` where `-` is for left-alignment and `d` is for integers:

```
s = num2str(x(:), '%-d');
ind = s(:,3)=='1'
```

and this also allows you to easily solve your first case:

```
ind = any(s=='1',2)
```

in either case to recover your original number just go:

```
x(ind)
```

Comment: I think your solution does not work as not all the numbers have the same amount of digits and we are counting from the left. With the TOs example your solution does not find the number 541846 (only 6 digits).

Comment: @Nras My bad, fixed now

Comment: There goes the -1 into a +1 :-).

Answer (score 1):

One way of getting there is to cast your numbers as strings and then check if the 3rd position of that string is `'1'`. It works perfectly fine in a loop, but I am confident that there is also a vectorized solution:

```
numbers = [6218473, 541846, 3115473, 175846]'
returned_numbers = [];

for i = 1:length(numbers)
    number = numbers(i);
    y = sprintf('%d', number) %// cast to string

    %// add number to list, if its third character is 11
    if strcmp(y(3), '1')
        returned_numbers = [returned_numbers, number];
    end
end

% // it returns:
returned_numbers =

 6218473      541846     3115473
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
%// Input array
array1 = [-94341 1234  4321 6515 847251737 6218473 541846 3115473 175846]

N = numel(array1); %// number of elements in input array
digits_sep = num2str(array1(:))-'0'; %//' Seperate the digits into a matrix

%// Simple case
output1 = array1(any(digits_sep==1,2))

%// More complex case output
col_num = 3;

%// Get column numbers for each row of the digits matrix and thus
%// the actual linear index corresponding to 3rd digit for each input element
ind1 =sub2ind(size(digits_sep),1:N,...
    size(digits_sep,2)-floor(log10(abs(array1))-col_num+1));

%// Select the third digits, check which ones have `1` and use them to logically 
%// index into input array to get the output
output2 = array1(digits_sep(ind1)==1)
```

Code run -

```
array1 =
      -94341        1234        4321        6515   847251737     6218473      541846     3115473      175846
output1 =
      -94341        1234        4321        6515   847251737     6218473      541846     3115473      175846
output2 =
        6515     6218473      541846     3115473
```